# Cannot exit normally when ssh'ing using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I have a script that ssh into a server and sets up an environment

```
ssh -t -t dev.example.com <<EOF
cd var/dev/
...other commands...
EOF
```

But when I type `exit` in the terminal after the script runs, it hangs and does not exit. The only way to exit is by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

How do I change this so I can type `exit` and it exits?

Comment: you can try `nohup ssh ...` .  Is one of your "other commands" left running?

Comment: yes, the last command spins up a ruby "irb" shell so I can interact with my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put after you ruby shell exit?

```
ssh -t -t dev.example.com <<EOF
cd var/dev/
...other commands...
exit
EOF
```

I am not sure about you ruby command, but this worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for me. Just hangs..

Comment: And this way? `ssh -t -t localhost "cd var/dev/; irb; exit"`. I can't reproduce your hang ...

Comment: Yes it worked for me!